# Implementing Quicksort in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, quicksort

My end goal is to have the quicksort algorithm demonstrated using moving blocks in html5 canvas. The issue I'm having is displaying quicksort at each stage as it is recursively called. The algorithms I've been trying to adapt return the sorted array at the end but I need to be able to draw out the array as it is sorted so the user can see how it works.

```
function quickSort (arr) {
    if (!arr.length)
        return arr

    var pivot = arr.splice(0, 1)
    var less = []
    var greater = []

    arr.forEach(function (el) {
        if (el <= pivot)
            less.push(el)
        else
            greater.push(el)         
    })

    return quickSort(less).concat(pivot, quickSort(greater))
}

var sorted = quickSort(bars2)

console.log('sorted', sorted)
```

Can anyone offer any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Look at [Friday Algorithms: Iterative Quicksort](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/06/18/friday-algorithms-iterative-quicksort/)

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, because to do this you'll have to ammend the code to introduce delays. Basically you'll want to paint the images of the in-progress right before each recursive call. Also, that's not really a quicksort implementation: quicksort is valuable because it's (supposed to be) **in-place**. The code you posted creates new arrays, and thus throws away the advantages of the algorithm. Of course, that may not matter for your illustration purposes, but the in-place partitioning is one of the interesting features, seems to me.

Comment: Yeah I realize for this purpose it won't actually be great for sorting. I just need to be able to demonstrate the concept.

Comment: You can implement the qsort as a functional program. Break up all qsort logic into functional parts, use a function stack to queue the functions. When you call a qSort function have it insert a render function at the bottom of the function stack. Thus you have qSortGetPiv() -> renderPiv() ->partistionItem()->renderItem()->partistionItem()->renderItem()->.... That will make it very easy to adapt the logic and show variations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this, [sorting algorithms visualized](http://math.hws.edu/eck/jsdemo/sortlab.html).

And here you have an implementation which you could modify if you want to do something similar, [Quick sort implementation](https://gist.github.com/paullewis/1981455).

Comment: Thanks, the second link has been really helpful. I am having some trouble understanding what's happening sometimes. In the partition function I've added:


    `console.log("pivot:" ,pivotValue);

    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    console.log("array position: ", array[i]);
    }`


When I run this array though: [25, 50, 10, 20, 30].


I get the following in the console: http://pastebin.com/jSqnrk5c


I understand that at first the pivot is moved to the end of the array, but don't understand how [25, 50, 10, 20, 30] becomes [30, 50, 10, 20, 25]

Comment: Writing that out has helped me understand, all good cheers :)

Comment: Good to hear you sorted it out :) Please mark as accepted answer if this solved your problem.